# Add units to polar coordinate scatter plot in python

Tags: python, plot, polar-coordinates

I have this polar scatter plot and I would like to show that distances from the origin are measured in centimeters by labelling the scale with a "cm." Any advice on how to do this?

[image: My plot]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


r = R
theta = o
colors = theta

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
c = plt.scatter(theta, r, cmap=plt.cm.hsv)
c.set_alpha(0.75)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you have examples or R, o and theta values?

Comment: I added a picture of the plot, would it help if I added the arrays too?

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding a label by use of `plt.set_ylabel` does not seem to work, sadly, as it always gets positioned at the origin. There is a simple way around it, though. You can introduce text with [`ax.text`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.text) at an arbitrary position. My suggestion would be, to move the tick labels away from the data to make sure that the label won't be misunderstood and then to introduce the label as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection="polar")
ax.set_rlabel_position(270)                        # Moves the tick-labels
ax.text(0.52, 0.25, "cm", transform=ax.transAxes)  # Adds text
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this:
[image: PolarImage]

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, that should work:

```
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,np.amax(r),3),["%.1f cm" % x for x in np.arange(0,np.amax(r),3)])
```

in `np.arange(0,np.amax(r),3)`  the 0 is just minimum tick you want in the graph, the 3 is step you want ticks should be.